# Missing Values when scraping table with Rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape the first  weather table from http://www.mlbdfsweather.com/ titled Weather Stats. For today's data, I'm able to scrape all the games except 3 of them. Why are some of the games missing ?

```
weather <- read_html("http://www.mlbdfsweather.com/") %>%
html_nodes("#table_1") %>%
html_table() %>%
data.frame()
```

Comment: Working as intended for me. I see 4 games on the site and I get 4 games from `rvest`

Comment: yah its working now. But when I was attempting there were 13 games listed and only ten would appear. weird. gonna give it another shot tomorrow. thanks

Comment: It's not working again as of today. It only scrapes the top 10 rows in the dataframe but leaves out the rest

Comment: I see it. It's because the table is build using a js library (`datatables` ) when navigating there are all the rows, but I guess rvest sees a pagination.